# Does the run pin p6 pin 2 connect to ground

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I already know that the run header resets the Pi. My question is does one of the pins lead directly to ground? I would like to use a common ground on the GPIO pins and connect it to the run pin 1.

Is this doable/safe?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which Pi model you mean.  However, I assume (but have not checked) that all run header implementations are the same.

On the Pi 3 Model B one of the run header pins is connected to ground.

See [Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (Reduced Schematics)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-3B-V1.2-Schematics.pdf):

[image: Raspberry-Pi-3B-V1.2-Schematics]

All Pi grounds are connected so it does not matter which ground you use.

Comment: Indeed I am using a raspberry pi 3. Because of this I was able to use a standard usb cable to run a power switch, reset switch, and power led on 1 common ground. THANKS!